# Controlling position of Legend in GGplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the below plot using `ggplot2`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
Dat = rbind(data.frame(var1 = 'x1', var2 = rnorm(1000, 10, 3)), 
            data.frame(var1 = 'x2', var2 = rnorm(1000, -10, 5)))

Dat %>% 
ggplot() +
    theme(
        legend.position = c(.15, .85)
    ) +

    geom_histogram(data = Dat, aes(x = var2, y = ..density.., fill = var1), position = "identity")
```

To control the legend's position, I used `legend.position`. However I observed that if change the plot size (i.e maximise the plot window), that position is getting changed.

I want legend should always stay in **top-left position** with a small margin irrespective of plot size. And legend must stay within the plot.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `legend.box.margin` theme setting to control the margins in absolute units, even if the legend is positioned and justified in a corner.

```r
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
Dat = rbind(data.frame(var1 = 'x1', var2 = rnorm(1000, 10, 3)), 
            data.frame(var1 = 'x2', var2 = rnorm(1000, -10, 5)))

ggplot(Dat) +
  geom_histogram(data = Dat, 
                 aes(x = var2, y = ..density.., fill = var1), 
                 position = "identity") +
  theme(
    legend.position = c(0,1), # top left position
    legend.justification = c(0, 1), # top left justification
    legend.box.margin = margin(5, l = 5, unit = "mm") # small margin
  )
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>